# SimpleXMLElement changing when passed to another function

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have a SimpleXMLElement variable that i've created programmatically.

I can print out that variables contents with `$xml->asXML();`

Here's the problem, before, the xml may have looked like this:

```
<Time DateType="VT" Value="23:59:59"/>
```

Now it'll look like this ***sometimes***:

```
<Time DateType="VT" Value="23:59:59"></@attributes></Time>
```

I have done absolutely nothing to the variable in between and it's being passed by reference.

I literally, print the xml, pass into the function and the first thing the function does it print the xml again, but it's now slightly different.

I say sometimes because only some nodes have this strange functionality applied to them.

Comment: Can you show the code that generates that xml element?

Comment: I have just solved it.

I was printing out the xml prior to this and this caused the xml to format it self.

Deleting the print_r($xml) before the print_r($xml->asXML()) solved it.

Comment: @ChrisG: Please add your finding as an answer below. You can then accept it later.